# How to Wake up a sleeping thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I made a thread at load event like below:

```
Thread checkAlert = null;
bool isStop = false;
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   checkAlert = new Thread(CheckAlert);
   checkAlert.Start();
} 
void CheckAlert()
{
   while (!isStop)
   {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        //do work here
   }
}
```

Is there any way to resume the checkAlert thread during it's sleep period?( `Thread.Sleep(60000);`)

I tried using `Thread.Interrupt()` but it flows a `ThreadInterruptedException`, how should I handle this exception? or is there any way to resume the thread?

---

Edited:

I need to wake up the thread before the "sleep" end because when the user wants to quit the program, the program will have to wait for some time before it really quits ( checkAlert is still running) Is there any way to improve this case?

Comment: No there is not, however if you explain what you are trying to do that "sleeping a thread and waking it up early" was your solution we can help you solve that problem instead. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Use AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(int) instead.  Now it is simple and clean.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I need this for several reasons, for example, when the user closes the form, the program will have to wait for some time before it really quits (the checkAlert Thread is still running), are there any ways to improve this situation?

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for your suggestion, but how do I use this?

Comment: @User2012384, you create the event outside the loop, then call yourEventName.WaitOne(60000); in place of the Sleep call you have now. This will wait for 60 seconds, just like Sleep, but if you need to wake it up sooner for shut-down, you can call yourEventName.Set();

Comment: the easiest thing would be to wrap a try/catch around `Thread.Sleep` -- the interrupt exception will be caught and sleep will end early, no? -- However, the best thing to do is probably use wait handles (`ManualResetEvent` for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments what it looks like is you need to re-design how `CheckAlert` works so it does not use Sleep's at all. What you should be doing is using a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = null;

public FrmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    //If you want OnTimedEvent to happen on the UI thread instead of a ThreadPool thread, uncomment the following line.
    //timer.SynchronizingObject = this;

    if(this.components == null)
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();

    //This makes it so when the form is disposed the timer will be disposed with it.
    this.componets.Add(timer);
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //It is good practice not to do complicated logic in a event handler
    // if we move the logic to its own method it is much easier to test (you are writing unit tests, right? ;) )
    CheckAlert();
}

void CheckAlert()
{
    //do work here
}

private void frmMain_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the thread to exit automatically when your program quits, simply make it a background thread.

```
checkAlert = new Thread(CheckAlert);
checkAlert.IsBackground = true;
checkAlert.Start();
```

Comment: I've tried making it a background thread just now, but the thread was still sleeping when I call Application.Exit()..

Comment: @User2012384 Yes, it will keep sleeping until `Program.Main` returns. `Application.Exit()` should still close the application.

Comment: When will the Program.Main return?

Comment: @User2012384 After `Application.Run` returns, which happens after you call `Application.Exit`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're trying to create a thread which handles two types of events: do something and stop running.

Rather than using a shared variable (`isStop`) and some other technique to interrupt the thread in order to do work, you might want to use threading events (not to be confused high-level UI `Event` objects) to control your thread.

```
AutoResetEvent stop = new AutoResetEvent(false);
AutoResetEvent check = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void CheckAlert() {
    WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[] { stop, check };
    for (;;) {
        switch (AutoResetEvent.WaitAny(handles)) {
            case 0:
                return;
            case 1:
                // do work
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `check.Set()` in your code will trigger the "do work" branch in the thread and `stop.Set()` will cause the thread to terminate gracefully.

Once your code has called `stop.Set()` to terminate the thread, it can call the thread's `Join()` method to wait until the thread terminates.

***EDIT***

I misunderstood the question. I will leave the code above in case anyone finds it useful.
If all you want to do is have a thread that performs a task once a minute and stop on demand, you can use the following code:

```
AutoResetEvent stop = new AutoResetEvent(false);

void CheckAlert() {
    var time = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // one minute
    while (!stop.WaitOne(time)) {
        // do work
    }
}

private Thread checkThread;

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    checkThread = new Thread(CheckAlert);
    checkThread.Start();
}

private void frmMain_Close(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    stop.Set();  // signal thread to stop
    checkThread.Join();  // wait for thread to terminate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the program needs to do work once a minute, how to call check.Set() once a minute?

Comment: @User2012384 - I may have misunderstood your question. Are you saying that you want it to perform a task once a minute and perform that same task on demand out of that once-a-minute cycle?

Comment: Actually the task is performed once a minute, and I use a thread to handle the task, everytime the task is executed, the thread will then sleep for one minute, and the reason why I need to "wake up" the thread during it's sleep period is that when the user closes the program, the program will have to wait for the thread to "wake up" before it really quits.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an explanation on how to wake a sleeping thread here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tttdef8x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

and this is a complete example (as you can see, Thread.Interrupt is the good choise... however you have to catch it to continue normal thread execution):

```
public class HVCSensor : HVCDevice, IDisposable
{
    private Thread myThread;
    private const int execute_timeout = ((10 + 10 + 6 + 3 + 15 + 15 + 1 + 1 + 15 + 10) * 1000);
    private bool disposed = false;
    private bool paused = false;

    public delegate void HVCResultsHandler(HVC_RESULT res);
    public event HVCResultsHandler HVCResultsArrived;

    private void OnHVCResultsArrived(HVC_RESULT res)
    {
        if (HVCResultsArrived != null) {
            HVCResultsArrived(res);
        }
    }

    public HVCSensor() {
        myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.execute));

    }

    private void execute(){
        while (!disposed) {
            if (!paused && this.IsConnected)
            {
                HVC_RESULT outRes;
                byte status;
                try
                {

                    this.ExecuteEx(execute_timeout, activeDetections, imageAcquire, out outRes, out status);
                    OnHVCResultsArrived(outRes);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
            else {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
                {

                }
            }


        }
    }

    public HVC_EXECUTION_IMAGE imageAcquire
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public HVC_EXECUTION_FLAG activeDetections
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void startDetection() {
        if(myThread.ThreadState==ThreadState.Unstarted)
            myThread.Start();
    }

    public void pauseDetection() {
        paused = true;
    }

    public void resumeDetection() {

        paused = false;
        if (myThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            myThread.Interrupt();

    }

    // Implement IDisposable. 
    // Do not make this method virtual. 
    // A derived class should not be able to override this method. 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        disposed = true;
        myThread.Interrupt();


    }

}
```